# Controller Method Get : Get specify attributes from a Class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webapi

my question is simple, I´m try to do a controller that pass some attributes of a Model

This is the method:

```
[HttpGet("getAllUserInfo")]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetAll() {
    var test = await _context.Users.ToListAsync(); //here I have the all Info of all users

    //In the return I want pass some attributes of user, creating a new object (ex: The user have a password but I don´t want to show that)
    return Ok(new { test.getType().Name, test.getType().Mail });
    //this above is the part of the code I don´t understand
    }
```

Is there any alternative to this scenario or what are the possible ideas to make this possible?

Sorry if there are any spelling mistakes in the title and document, but I think the idea where I have difficulty understanding is there

Comment: I doubt a `getType()` method exists unless you wrote it.

Comment: David's answer covers simple enough cases. For more sophisticated ones, you'd probably want to create "DTO" versions of your Entity classes and then maybe use some tool like AutoMapper or Mapster or manual mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to project a list of objects into a new list of different objects?  You can do that with `.Select()`.  For example:

```
return Ok(test.Select(t => new { Name = t.Name, Mail = t.Mail }));
```

Comment: Yes, but with that example, it give be not a error but unfortunately gives me a empty object [] , but let me see if the post method is the problem cuz i m having some problems with the bd

Comment: @JoséCarlos: If this produces an empty collection then `test` was an empty collection.  What debugging have you done to indicate otherwise?

Comment: the problem has resolve and the example you give me it works, thank you

Comment: @David This advice by Carlos works, but according to solid principles this approach is bad. Suppose that you will have other Get by Id method. Here you will return new {....} as well. It breaks principle "Don't repeat yourself" Best approach here is to use the mapping service to convert your dto models (after to ListAsync) to view models. See: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html